# Unable to dismiss dialog in runOnUiThread

Tags: android, barcode-scanner

I'm scanning QR code using Google's Vision. I got help from this [link](http://www.devexchanges.info/2016/10/reading-barcodeqr-code-using-mobile.html). I want to show AlertDialog after getting the value from QR code. If I directly show alertdialog inside receiveDetections() method I'm getting "Can't create looper" error. So I called the alertdialog inside runOnUiThread(). But now I'm unable to dismiss the dialog. Would like to know what's the reason for this.

```html
@Override
public void receiveDetections(Detector.Detections<Barcode> detections){
                final SparseArray<Barcode> barcodes = detections.getDetectedItems();
                if (barcodes.size() != 0) {
                    
                   runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            try {

                               
                                String val = barcodes.valueAt(0).displayValue;
                                showAlert(val);

                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                           }

                        }
                    });


}
```

```html
private void showAlert(String val){
        try {
            

            if (!val.equals("")) {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ScannedBarcodeActivity.this);
                builder.setTitle(emp.getName())
                        .setPositiveButton(newStatus, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                emp.setStatus(newStatus);
                                viewModel.updateEmployee(emp);
                                dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        })
                        .setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        });
                AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
                alertDialog.show();

            }

        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Even though now the alertdialog is showing, when I click CANCEL button, the alert does not gets dismissed.

Answer (score 0):

I think `receiveDetections` is being called more than once, which is resulting in multiple instances of AlertDialog. So when you press **CANCEL** button you might be cancelling only one of those multiple opened dialogs.

You can add logs to see how many times `receiveDetections` is being called, or just hit **CANCEL** button multiple times and all the previously opened alerts will be cancelled

*Possible Reason:
**receiveDetections** will be executed every-time your camera passes image to QRScanner,
and as your camera is continuously streaming images, QRScanner is calling **receiveDetections** again and again.

Comment: @somnath-pal Would you mind elaborating the reason of downVoting?

Comment: I didn't downvoted you. Someone else did. I upvoted you. Your explanation was correct and when I used singe instance of AlertDialog, it got dismissed.

Answer (score -1):

The reason why you alert dialog is not dismissing because you are new object of AlertDialog each time when `receiveDetections` called and in your case `receiveDetections` multiple time.

You have to create a Singleton class object:

```
 public class singleTonDialogExample {
       static TextToSpeech t1;
       private static singleTonExample ourInstance = new singleTonDialogExample();
       private Context appContext;
       private ICallBack iCallBack;

      public interface ICallBack{
       void onYesPressed();
       void onNoPressed();
      }

       private singleTonDialogExample() { }
       public static Context get() {
          return getInstance().getContext();
       }
       public static synchronized singleTonDialogExample getInstance() {
          return ourInstance;
       }
       public void init(Context context) {
          if (appContext = = null) {
             this.appContext = context;
          }
       }
       private Context getContext() {
          return appContext;
       }

       public void setICallBack(ICallBack callBack){
         this.iCallBack=callBack;
       }
       public void AlertDialog(final MainActivity mainActivity,String title,String message) {
          AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mainActivity);
          alertDialogBuilder.setMessage(message);
          alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("yes",
          new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
             @Override
             public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                iCallBack.onYesPressed();
             }
          });
          alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
             @Override
             public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                  iCallBack.onNoPressed();
             }
           });
           AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
           alertDialog.show();
        }
    }
```

Create the Dialog in Activity like this:

```
  singleTonDialogExample dialog;
  dialog = singleTonExample.getInstance();
  dialog.init(getApplicationContext());
  dialog.setICallBack(this);
  dialog.AlertDialog(MainActivity.this,"Title","This is message");
```

Also implement the `ICallBack` interface in your activity or fragment.